Reference to mint is not recognized in Struct creation while trying to create an NFT in Anchor
I've tried to follow and complete the following guide to create an NFT through Anchor, but after finishing writing the code following each step throroughly following error while compiling:
error[E0425]: cannot find value `mint` in this scope
   --> programs/solana-try-nft/src/lib.rs:144:36
    |
144 |     address=find_metadata_account(&mint.key()).0,
    |                                    ^^^^ not found in this scope
    |
help: consider importing this function
    |
1   + use anchor_spl::token::accessor::mint;
    |

error[E0425]: cannot find value `mint` in this scope
   --> programs/solana-try-nft/src/lib.rs:150:42
    |
150 |     address=find_master_edition_account(&mint.key()).0,
    |                                          ^^^^ not found in this scope
    |
help: consider importing this function
    |
1   + use anchor_spl::token::accessor::mint;
    |

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0425`.
error: could not compile `solana-try-nft` (lib test) due to 2 previous errors
Error: Building IDL failed 

This is the struct I am trying to create:
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InitNFT<'info> {
    /// CHECK: ok, we are passing this account ourselves
    #[account(mut, signer)]
    pub signer: AccountInfo<'info>,
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = signer,
        mint::decimals = 0,
        mint::authority = signer.key(),
        mint::freeze_authority = signer.key(),
    )]
    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = signer,
        associated_token::mint = mint,
        associated_token::authority = signer,
    )]
    pub associated_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    /// CHECK - address
    #[account(
        mut,
        address=find_metadata_account(&mint.key()).0,
    )]
    pub metadata_account: AccountInfo<'info>,
    /// CHECK: address
    #[account(
        mut,
        address=find_master_edition_account(&mint.key()).0,
    )]
    pub master_edition_account: AccountInfo<'info>,

    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
    pub token_metadata_program: Program<'info, Metadata>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>
}

Both lines that refer to the address like address=find_master_edition_account(&mint.key()).0, and address=find_metadata_account(&mint.key()).0, where a reference to mint is used are being flagged as mint not known in the scope. Despite having imported the needed dependencies. How could I fix this?

if you are passing &mint.key() to a function and Rust says it can't find mint in scope, the problem must be in the calling code, which you have not shared. It might be helpful to take a close look at how the mint variable is instantiated there and why it isn't in scope when it is passed to the find_* functions.
